# In Treeview, how do I sort the numbers in a given column in descending order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

How can i sort the Badge column numbers in descending order (9, 7, 5, 4, 3, 1)? Naturally, by ordering the Badge numbers, the order of the lines will also change.
[image]

I would like to get:

```
5,"Frank","9"
3,"Daniel","7"
4,"Leonard","5"
1,"Jack","4"
6,"Robert","3"
2,"Tom","1"
```

What am I doing wrong in my code?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

ws = Tk()
ws.title('PythonGuides')
ws.geometry('400x300')
ws['bg']='#fb0'

data  = [
    [1,"Jack","4"],
    [2,"Tom","1"],
    [3,"Daniel","7"],
    [4,"Leonard","5"],
    [5,"Frank","9"],
    [6,"Robert","3"],
    ]

tv = ttk.Treeview(ws)
tv['columns']=('Rank', 'Name', 'Badge')
tv.column('#0', width=0, stretch=NO)
tv.column('Rank', anchor=CENTER, width=80)
tv.column('Name', anchor=CENTER, width=80)
tv.column('Badge', anchor=CENTER, width=80)
tv.heading('#0', text='', anchor=CENTER)
tv.heading('Rank', text='Id', anchor=CENTER)
tv.heading('Name', text='rank', anchor=CENTER)
tv.heading('Badge', text='Badge', anchor=CENTER)
tv.pack()


def func1():
    rows = [(tv.set(item, "Badge"), item) for item in tv.get_children('')]
    rows.sort(reverse=True)

    for index, record in enumerate(data):
        Rank = record[0]
        Name = record[1]
        Badge = record[2]
        
        datagrid = [Rank, Name, Badge]
        tv.insert(parent='', index='end', values=(datagrid))
    

button = Button(ws, text="Button", command = func1)
button.place(x=1, y=1)

ws.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to sort the rows after you insert the data and then move the lines accordingly

```
def func1():
    for record in data:
        tv.insert(parent='', index='end', values=record)

    rows = [(tv.set(item, "Badge"), item) for item in tv.get_children('')]
    rows.sort(reverse=True)
    for index, (val, k) in enumerate(rows):
        tv.move(k, '', index)
```

You could also simply sort `data`

```
data.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[-1]), reverse=True)


def func1():
    for record in data:
        tv.insert(parent='', index='end', values=record)
```

[image]

Notice I simplified `func1` data insertion, there is no need to unpack every list just to repack it